# Can't get twiny() to align X axis correctly in histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to add a second x-axis label to the top of a plot. The normal axis is in log scale and displays as 10^-1, 10^0, etc, as it should, but I also want ticks at each 10^x.5 along the top (.1, .32, 1, 3.2, etc). When I try to do this with twiny, they align completely incorrectly and in a way that I can't even understand the reason for. Here is my code (and the resulting plot):

```
from pylab import *
import numpy as np

dfile = "data.txt"                       #DATA STUFF YOU DON'T NEED
data = np.loadtxt(dfile,dtype=float)
asep = data[:,1]
par= data[:,2]
dist = 1000/par
dsep = asep*dist
ldsep = np.log10(dsep)


#RELEVANT BITS

ax1=subplot(211)
ax1.set_xlim([0,100])
plt.gca().set_xscale("log")
plt.hist(allsep,bins=[.1,.32,1,3.2,10,32,100],facecolor='red')
plt.ylabel('$N_{stars}$')

ax2 = ax1.twiny()
ax2.set_xscale("log")
newpos=[.1,.32,1,3.2,10,32,100]
newlabel=[0.1,0.32,1.0,3.2,10,32,100]
ax2.set_xticks(newpos)
ax2.set_xticklabels(newlabel)
ax2.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')
ax2.xaxis.set_label_position('top')
ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())




#SECOND PLOT, NOT REALLY NECESSARY
ax3=subplot(212)
ax3.set_xlim([0,100])
plt.hist(allsep,bins=[0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75,80],facecolor='red')
plt.xlabel('Projected Separation (AU)')
plt.ylabel('$N_{stars}$')


plt.savefig('dhist.png',dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

When I try to run your code,  the first error message is `UserWarning: Attempted to set non-positive xlimits for log-scale axis;...`
So - what versions of python and matplotlib do you use? Perhaps you should consider an update.

But still,  before that you could simply first test what happens if you change the setting of x-axis limits to [ 0.1,... ]:

```
ax1.set_xlim([0.1,100])
```